# Accessing DataTable item returns incorrect selected item when order is changed

Tags: jsf, primefaces

To better read the contents of a cell within a dataTable, I used a commandLink to bring up a dialog box.

This works fine as long as the sortOrder of the dataTable is set to ascending. Upon using sortOrder desc and clicking the commandLink, the dialog brings up the result of the item that would have been there, had the sortOrder been ascending (in other words, in a desc dataTable -8,7,....,2,1- with 8 rows, clicking on row with id =2 will bring up the contents of row id=7).

What causes this mix-up in IDs? Am I not storing the actual clicked on item in the backing bean temporarily, which should not be affected by the sortOrder? IS there a better practice for what I am trying to accomplish?

PF version 5.3, JSF 2.2.7

dataTable and dialog

```
<p:dataTable id="improvementTable" var="improvement" widgetVar="improvementsTable" value="#{Controller.improvements}" sortBy="#{improvement.id}" sortOrder="descending">
    <p:column headerText="ID">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText value="#{improvement.id}" />
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputText id="modelInput" value="#{improvement.id}" />
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <p:commandLink id="detailOut" value="#{improvement.detail}" action="#{Controller.setSelectedImprovement(improvement)}" process="@this" oncomplete="PF('wDetail').show();" update=":dlgDetail" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
</h:form>
<p:dialog id="dlgDetail" widgetVar="wDetail">
    <h:outputText value="#{Controller.selectedImprovement.detail}" />
</p:dialog>
```

In the Bean

```
@ManagedBean (name="Controller")  
@RequestScoped  
public class Controller{   

    private List<Improvement> improvements;   
    private Improvement selectedImprovement;

    @PostConstruct
    public void load()  {  
        CIMImprovementDao cimDao = new CIMImprovementDao();
        improvements = cimDao.getAll();
    }    

    public List<Improvement> getImprovements() {  
        return improvements;  
    }  

    public Improvement getSelectedImprovement() {
        return selectedImprovement;
    }

    public void setSelectedImprovement(Improvement selectedImprovement) {
        this.selectedImprovement = selectedImprovement;
    }

}
```

Comment: Try to add the sorter in the column.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I tried using the sorter in the column but I still have the same issue.

Comment: Post all the table

Comment: Added the table (with sortOrder asc, problem occurs when sortOrder is set to desc)

Comment: Please format the code with indentation. And try making a [mcve] and post version info both of PF and JSF (and the implementation)

Comment: I edited the edit :). I'll try to minimize the code some more too.

Comment: It is NOT only about minimizing. It is about 'complete' and 'verifiable' too. And indentation.

Comment: And PLEASE try PF 5.3 or 6.0 or 6.1 or 6.2... please.... 5.2 is rather old. That is why I maybe had a deja-vu (of something being fixed in the last 3 years). ALWAYS try a latest version before posting and check issue lists. If you have an mcve, this costs way less time than posting a question here

Comment: I have edited the entire question (with indents,minimized, and checked that the issue can still be recreated). I am actually using PF 5.3 (and I am currently limited to that version). I'll see if I can test it elsewhere with 6.0. I have tried looking up if this was a known issue, but did not find anything relevant yet.

Comment: Sorry, I read 5.2. If you make a [mcve] it should be very easy to test in a new project with new versions (having a 'dummy' project for things like debugging/issues is always good) ;-). Related: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1442 ?

Comment: I personally always use LazyDataModel and especially https://github.com/omnifaces/optimusfaces Saves a lot of code boilerplate... Really cool (like omnifaces)